# Convergence of sum of Bernoullis

Tags: probability

Let $X=\sum_{i}^n X_i$ where the $X_i$ are independent Bernoulli random variables which equal $1$ with probability $i/N$ and $0$ otherwise. Assume $n \leq N$.   Does the cdf of $X$ converge to the cdf of $\operatorname{Pois}(\mathbb{E}(X))$ as $n$ tends to infinity? If so, what does this tell us about tail bounds for $X$?

Comment: The answer depends on how $N$ tends to infinity as a function of $n$. If $N=n$ always, then $\mathbb E(X)$ is unbounded (as a function of $n$), for example.

Comment: Why does it matter if $\mathbb{E}(X)$ grows with $n$?  If $N=n$ then $\mathbb{E}(X) = N(N+1)/2N$ . For a particular problem instance $n$ and $N$ are just fixed and large.

Comment: If $\mathbb E(X)$ is unbounded, then the cdf can't converge to a fixed finite cdf.

Comment: @GregMartin $\operatorname{Pois}(\mathbb{E}(X))$  also depends on $n$ and $N$ so couldn't they still converge in some useful sense?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "useful".

Answer (score 1):

In your case of Bernoulli variables, it holds that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \overset{D}{\rightarrow} Pois(\lambda) \iff \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X_i=1) \overset{n}{\rightarrow} \lambda \iff \frac{n(n+1)}{2N_n}\overset{n}{\rightarrow} \lambda$$
So it works iff $N \in \Theta(n^2)$ (meaning: $N$ asymptotically grows exactly as fast as $n^2$).

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure I understand your proof however. If $n= N/100$, for example, what does the distribution of $X$ look like?

Comment: Are you using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution for convergence?

Comment: (Edited). In this case we have $\sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i = 1) = \lambda_n$.  Can we say something similar to $X \overset{D}{\rightarrow} \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda_n)$?

Comment: The first equivalence is an advanced form of the Poisson Limit Theorem where identical distribution is not necessary. For a quick Wikipedia link, I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem is the closest I can find.

Comment: Yes, I'm using $D$ for convergence in distribution.

You will get $X \overset{D}{\rightarrow} Pois(\lim_{n \to \infty}\lambda_n)$ iff $0<\lim_{n \to \infty}\lambda_n<\infty$

Comment: @Fylos What does the distribution look like otherwise if not Poisson when the mean tends to infinity?

Comment: @user66652 In this case you have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(X_i=1)=\infty$.
Using the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) you get
$P(\{X_i=1 \text{ for infinitely many i's}\})=1$
and thus
$P(X=\infty)=1$ so $X=\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: @Fylos I think the OP is asking something a little different.  As far as I can tell marais wants to know if $X$ and $Pois(E(X))$ are very similar when $n$ is fixed but very big.

Comment: @Raphael In this case Le Cam's theorem from above is also useful: It says that the density function of $X$ uniformely converges to the density function of $Pois(E(X))$ and the speed of convergence is related to how quickly the $p_i=P(X_i=1)$ tend to zero for $(i \to \infty)$. In short terms: Yes, they are very similar.